# Make a grid easily in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids

I do not like the youtube link showing how to do a grid in photoshop.  It is really archaic, drawing line by line etc etc.
I have a portrait that I need to draw grid over.  Is there a simple way in Photoshop CC?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the grid... @whytek suggested guide solutions, but who knows what kind of grid you're after.

Comment: What youtube link?

Comment: What type of grid are you looking to create? One just for reference and alignment (View->Show->Grid)? Or a grid of guides (use the extension [GuideGuide](http://guideguide.me/)? Or a grid that will be visible on the finished image or print? Please specify.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, yes there is. And here's how:

1. View -> New guide layout and there you can define your grid the way you want.
2. View -> New guides from shape, a more complex method of doing your guides, but it may suit you best.
3. A plugin called guide guide, just type it's name in any serach engine and you'll find it (unfortunately it's not free to use - costs 10$, but comes with a lot of handy presets).

Hope that helped!